# Undefined control sequence - output.bbl with DOI

Tags: bibtex

I am having issues with printing out the bibliography on a specific reference with the following document on Overleaf

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Shared Resources}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\cite{chalkUniversalShapeReplicators2017}

\bibliographystyle{plainurl}
\bibliography{bibs}

\end{document}
```

The citation in `bibs.bib` is as follows:

```
@inproceedings{chalkUniversalShapeReplicators2017,
  title = {Universal Shape Replicators via {{Self-Assembly}} with {{Attractive}} and {{Repulsive Forces}}},
  booktitle = {Proceedings of the {{Twenty-Eighth Annual ACM-SIAM Symposium}} on {{Discrete Algorithms}}},
  author = {Chalk, Cameron and Demaine, Erik D. and Demaine, Martin L. and Martinez, Eric and Schweller, Robert and Vega, Luis and Wylie, Tim},
  year = {2017},
  month = jan,
  pages = {225--238},
  publisher = {{Society for Industrial and Applied Mathematics}},
  isbn = {978-1-61197-478-2},
  doi = {10.1137/1.9781611974782.15},
  langid = {english}
}
```

I get the following error code:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.18   {\path
             {doi:10.1137/1.9781611974782.15}}.
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

However when I remove the DOI, the error is not present. How can I keep the DOI in the bibliography, and prevent the error from cropping up?

### Solution

Thanks to @moewe for the fix, adding `\usepackage{hyperref}` solved all issues

Comment: your bib style seems to be assuming the `url` package is loaded.

Comment: If you want clickable links, you might as well go for `\usepackage{hyperref}`. If for some reason you don't want clickable links, load `\usepackage{url}`. (`\usepackage{hyperref}` automatically loads `\usepackage{url}`, so you don't need to load both at the same time.)

Comment: moewe thanks - `hyperref` was needed to resolve the issue.